# Perl convert string to numeric number

Tags: perl, perl-module

I want to convert a string ordinal to a number in perl 
I have searched but not get exact answer.

Example: if the input is

```
one it should be 1.
five hundred it should be 500.
three hundred it should be 300.
```

Is there any module to do this?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

One of the best parts of Perl is CPAN and, sure enough, a couple minutes of poking around on [metacpan](https://metacpan.org/) turned up the [Lingua::EN::Words2Nums](https://metacpan.org/pod/Lingua::EN::Words2Nums) module:

```
use Lingua::EN::Words2Nums;
$num=words2nums("two thousand and one");
$num=words2nums("twenty-second");
$num=words2nums("15 billion, 6 million, and ninteen");
```

Comment: Thanks a lot Dave, It works fine.

Comment: I wonder if "ninteen" really works!

Comment: 15 billion, 6 million, and ninteen `15006000019`

Comment: @Borodin - The original version of my answer included a comment that he might need to fix the spelling of "hundared" before it would work. Then I saw in the documentation that _"Various mispellings of numbers are understood."_